# Can I inspect the database in the current transaction when debugging?

Tags: java, mysql, debugging

I have a Java web app (Jetty over MySQL). I'm trying to find a bug in a big chunk of code, all under one transaction. It would be useful to be able to inspect the database at certain points in the code - is there a nice way to do it (some tool or Eclipse plugin)?

I'm looking for something like the inspector available for HSQLDB. I could probably get hold of the current session and run arbitrary XML on it via 'Expressions' view in Eclipse debug mode, but that won't be pretty, I'm sure.

*EDIT:* scratch that, I only now noticed that what I thought was some special tool that comes with HSQLDB is merely an internal wrapper for DatabaseManagerSwing. I'll try to bend it to my will.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using raw JDBC, the you probably should see [MySQL Driver Properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), and more particularly the "Debugging/Profiling"  section.